# Use external Libs in UI5 Full-stack Webide

Tags: sapui5

how i can use the installed libs in my controller in the fullstack webide? whats the path to it? is it even possible? my package-json.lock have the lib. but i cant figure out how to import it in the controller in the define options.

Thanks

Comment: You are missing something. package.json is available in your app because Web IDE uses tools like Grunt and UI5 Tooling to serve your app. If what you want is to install a npm package and use it inside your UI5 app, forget it. You are confuse about the back end needed to host/serve your app and the front end app. Your app is most likely located inside the `webapp` folder and it's totally possible to use external (front end) libs inside your app. There are different ways of achieving that, I personally use the `resources` attribute inside the `sap.ui5` section of the manifest.json file (...)

Comment: See https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html#loiobe0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da/section_sap_app

Comment: @fabiopagoti hmmmm are you sure about it? i mean when i build my app it does npm rum so the dependencies will be installed when I configure it in the package-JSON.lock. I mean yes i know i can import to my webapp folder and use it.. but it is in my opinion not the beautyful way. I just want to import it.. but maybe i missing something. Like "foo requires 'bar' or import from 'foo'" but just in the ui5 way. like sap.define[ "thirdparty/libs/foo,...]  do you have an example for me maybe?

Comment: Yes I am sure. Ui5 apps are web application which run on the browser and not on a node runtime

Comment: UI5 is not a template engine either

Comment: Yes you can do it easily, check this example https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/pages/extensibility/ProjectShims/#example-a